# displaying output in a different terminal of unix after splitting terminal horizontally using screen command

Tags: bash, shell

I have a putty session in which I have used screen command to split the terminal into half horizontally,can you tell me how do I split the terminal into 3 windows using screen command.
Also I need the ouptut of the program in first terminal to be displayed in second window can you tell me how to do it? 
for eg:in screen1: I have a menu like:1) do this 
                                      2) do that

In screen2: I need the output of 1)do this to be dislayed.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no direct way to provide output in a different terminat - but there is a simple workaround:

**screen1:** yourcommand > tempfile

**screen2:** tail -f tempfile

Comment: I have a putty session in which I have used screen command to split the terminal into half horizontally,can you tell me how do I split the terminal into 3 windows using screen command.

Comment: press "C-a S"[Control-a shift-s] twice - you can find more shortcuts at the quick-reference guide: http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference

Comment: i know the shortcuts, can you tell me if there's a way i can implement this in a bash script

Answer (score 0):

> I have a putty session in which I have used screen command to split
>   the terminal into half horizontally,can you tell me how do I split the
>   terminal into 3 windows using screen command.

Split off a new *region*:

```
screen -X split
```

Create a *window* in the region:

```
screen -X eval "focus" "screen _command_" "focus up"
```

`_command_` might be the abovementioned `tail -f tempfile`.